# Overlap and center an image

Tags: html, css

I want to have four buttons (anchors) taking up a fourth of the screen each. I want my teams logo in the middle overlapping all four buttons, centered on the page.

```css
.forsaken {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<img src="icon5.png" class="forsaken">
```

Comment: why not a fiddle we can play with in stead of the pastebin? Also, that little code, you should really put it in your question for future reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use div's. Here is one: http://pastebin.com/12LKEh5x

Just wrap the buttons in a div with the example above, then make another that has a z:index = 2 so it goes over the first one with the z:index = 1.